# spring batch writer append data from next line

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Hi i am new to this spring batch. I am reading data from database and write it to text file. I am appending data to existing file.i can do that but i want to append data in file from the new line....

Example....
existing text file is like.

Hi I am new to spring batch.

so now when I am writing other data from flatfileitemwriter it append directly next to that line.i want it to write it from the next line as..

Hi I am new to spring batch. But i will learn it.

but now it prints as....

Hi I am new to spring batch.But i will learn it.

so please help me in this.....

here is my writer..

```
<bean id="dbToFileItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="file:${Subrogrationoutfile}" />
        <property name="appendAllowed" value="true"/>
        <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="com.hcsc.ccsp.nonadj.subrogration.batch.SubrogrationLineAggregator"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

and my aggregator is

```
public class SubrogrationLineAggregator extends PassThroughLineAggregator<Subrogration>{
    @Override
public  String aggregate(Subrogration subrogration){

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


                   //logic

        return result.toString();

    }
```

Comment: add a new line character first.

Comment: Are you using `<property name="appendAllowed" value="true" />` for `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter`.

Comment: yes i am using that for append operation.
but the problem is that when i use that it start writing at the end of the statement.
i want to write that from the very next line

Comment: are you using any `lineAggregator`?

Comment: Yes, I am using PassThroughLineAggregator...

Comment: Please see my edited question...thnak you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `FlatFileItemWriter` uses default line separator

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

I think you have overridden this value some where in your code.

---

For more info read [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/1.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.java#FlatFileItemWriter.%3Cinit%3E%28%29).

Here is the piece of code from `write()` method of `FlatFileItemWriter`

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {

    ...
    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
    int lineCount = 0;
    for (T item : items) {
        lines.append(lineAggregator.aggregate(item) + lineSeparator);
        lineCount++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'll look into after some time. Right now I am busy.

Comment: Please have a look at [Writing single line file using FlatFileItemWriter](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/48135-writing-single-line-file-using-flatfileitemwriter)